# test joint equality of different regression models' predictions at a given point

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, prediction, asymptotics

We have $k$ datasets, each consists of $Y^{(i)}$ and $X^{(i)}$ for $i = 1,\dots, k$. Both $Y^{(i)}$ and $X^{(i)}$ are vectors of length $n_i$. For each dataset we regress $Y$ on $X$, so we have $k$ regression models:
\begin{align}
&y^{(1)} = x^{(1)}\beta^{(1)}+\epsilon\\
&\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\vdots\\
&y^{(k)} = x^{(k)}\beta^{(k)}+\epsilon
\end{align}

Now for a point $x_0$, I want to test joint equality of 
\begin{align}
&H_0:E{y}^{(1)}=E{y}^{(2)}=\dots=E{y}^{(k)}\>{\rm at}\>x_0\\
&H_1: {\rm Not}\> H_0
\end{align}

Comment: Well you know whether the true values are equal already!  I suspect what you want is to test the joint equality of the expected values of the $y^{(i)}$, which would be estimated by the fitted values.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Fitted values are asymptotically normal with mean being the expected values of $y$, that is $x\beta$. This sounds like one way ANOVA - testing equality of population means. But it won’t work here because for each population we only observe one data point (one fitted value)... I suppose I can do some sort of bootstrap but I would really like an asymptotic test.

Comment: Not really a problem; you have an (estimated) covariance matrix for $\hat{\beta}$, so can calculate an (estimated) variance for $x\hat{\beta}$.  You then have, for each of your $k$ regressions, an estimated mean $\hat{y}^{(j)}$ and variance of same, so you can still do your one way ANOVA.

Comment: Actually, I have $x\hat{\beta}\sim N(x\beta, \hat{se}(\beta)x)$ for all $k$ regressions. But isn't the fitted value $x\hat{\beta}$ just one sample from the Normal distribution. That's why I was saying that we only have one sample per population. I'm quite confused can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks! For example if we have $y_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$, how'd we test $\mu_i=\dots=\mu_k$ if we only have one sample from each of the Normals.